# Algorithm for inversion in truncated polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, cryptography

I have a paper that describes an algorithm for finding the inverse of a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^N-1)$:
[image]

I want to implement it in code, but I'm having difficulties to understand it. I hope someone could answer me the following questions to clarify mu dubts:

1. The paper specifies that all computations are done modulo 3, and thus the coefficients are choosen from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$. Is it because we are talking about $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? Some implementations in code seem to use coefficients in the set $\{0,1,2\}$. Is there any difference or are these sets equivalent?
2. Step 4 involves a division and multiplication by $X$. I think that dividing by $X$ means multiplying by the inverse of $X$, but I don't know if that inverse should be calculated modulo 3 or if it is the inverse of $X$ in the stated ring. Same question applies to the star multiplication by $X$.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Please give a link or citation for the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is not a variable ranging over $\Bbb{Z}_3$. It is an indeterminate. So division by $X$ should be polynomial division (division modulo three is meaningless). Think about the situation in Step 3. You have a polynomial $f(X)$. If $f_0=0$ it means that the constant term of $f(X)$ is zero.
So at this step you are required to, for example, divide
$$f(X)=X-X^2+X^5-X^6$$
by $X$, and come up with $f(X)/X=1-X+X^4-X^5$. Or, taking into account the do-while loop, divide something like
$$f(X)=X^4+X^5+X^6-X^{11}$$ by $X$ four times to end up with $1+X+X^2-X^7$. The point is that when exiting this loop $f(X)$ must have a non-zero constant term.

If you store a polynomial as an array of its coefficients, division by $X$ amounts to stripping the leading zeros from that array (and padding them to the high degree end).

---

In the step where you are to multiply $c(X)$ by $X$ you must take care not to let the array of coefficients of $c(X)$ overflow from the high end. The algebra is done modulo $X^N-1$, meaning that if $c(X)*X$ get a term of degree $N$, you reduce it modulo $X^N-1$, whence $X^N=1$. So if you represent
$$c(X)=c_0+c_1X+c_2X^2+\cdots+c_{N-1}X^{N-1}$$
with the array $(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{N-1})$, then $c(X)*X$ becomes
the array $(c_{N-1},c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{N-2})$. In other words, multiplication by $X$ amounts to a cyclic shift to the right for the list of coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your simple explanation, it was really helpful! I would like to go deeper on my understanding of how these operations on algebraic structures work. Do you know any good book or any kind of resource, though not really advanced, to learn about this?